# Web Core API - cannot get the correct URL for the deployed server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

I am able to make calls to my deployed Web API Core from C# code, but from AJAX I get a 404 error.
My JQuery code is as follows;

```
var removeUser = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $container = $this.closest(".container");
    $container.uniqueId();
    $.list.container = $container;
    $.list.id = $container.id;
    var $row = $this.closest(".row");
    $.list.row = $row;
    var userId = $this.data("sir-remove-id");
    var $sectionId = $this.closest("section")[0].id;
    var url;
    var callback = removeUserFromView;
    if ($sectionId === "SuperUserList") {
        url = GetHiddenField("sir-user-root-url") + userId + "/removeSuperUser";
    } else {
        var container = $("#" + $container[0].id);
        var item = container.find(".contractId");
        var contractId = item.val();
        url = GetHiddenField("sir-user-root-url") + contractId + "/" + userId + "/removeContractUser";
    }

    dataService.removeFromDatabase(callback, url);
}
```

And in dataService;

```
removeFromDatabase = function (callback, url) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "DELETE"
            }).done(
                function (data) {
                    callback(data);
                });
        },
```

In development my call to

```
http://localhost:xxx//api//users//18/removeSuperUser
```

works

But on my test server I get a 404 for

```
http://testweb.xxx.com//api//users//27/removeSuperUser
```

On the web API Core, the signature is

```
namespace Properties.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/users")]
    public class UserPermissionsController : BaseSirController
    {
       [HttpDelete("{userId}/removeSuperUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveSuperUser(int userId)
        {
```

So why am I getting a 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that what I had missed is that the deployed URL needed to include the name of the application. Once I put that in it worked.